# CSS: Multiple `!important` instances on the same Class

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a, for me, strange situation that I have never came across before.

I have created a `class` that defines a `font-size` of `0.8vw`
If the screen-size-width is smaller then 750px a new `media query` is loaded where the `font-size` is `3.2vw`.

Because this is the same class I have to use `!important` on the 750px query.

Here comes the problem.... If, and there is, there will be another `media-query` I have to use another `!important` but as far as I know that won't be possible.

I'm starting to think that I don't fully understand how to use the `media-queries` in combination with different styles.

Here is an example of how this should go:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .header_devider{
    font-size: 3.2vw !important;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .header_devider{
    font-size: 4vw !important;
  }
}

.header_devider{
    font-size: 0.8vw;
}

<div class="header_devider">
    test content
</div>
```

Hope somebody can tell me how to fix this.

M.

Comment: it is possible, that one counts, that lastest one (sorry for my english)

Comment: @Paulie_D Allright. I'll post some examples.....

Comment: as long as your media query is after your initial declaration (and to the same specificity), you shouldn't need to include the `!important` to override it.  If you do, it means you have a more specific selector somewhere else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your media queries **after** your initial style declaration and it should work:

```css
.header_devider {
  font-size: 0.8vw;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .header_devider {
    font-size: 3.2vw;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .header_devider {
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't know that the order mathered. Thnx I'll go try that!

Comment: Damn. Thank you. Really. Thank you..... This is so valuable to me! FYI: The Fiddle didn't work on my end (chrome) but my website did work!

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.  Been having trouble with the new version of fiddle - seems to be some sort of caching going on with it so never sure if it saves properly. I'll remove it from my answer

Comment: This could be a useful article for you to read: http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/ the rule described in the answer is number 4 of the cascade section

Comment: Thnx. This is interesting